# Google scripts "Document inaccessible"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

For the past 24 hours or so I have been trying to run my script and it keeps saying "The document is inaccessible. Please try again later." This started happening without me making any changes to my script.
Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: You should add more background info, and maybe a screenshot, to help us understand what the problem is and why it is occurring.

Comment: This kind of posts (Anyone have any idea what's going on?) are more appropiate for a social network. Checkout the [Google Apps Script Community on G+](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Answer (score 1):

## Possibly

The account you're trying to view the script from isn't your default account (the first account you sign in with, before switching accounts).  Sign out and sign back in with the account you want to use.